# How can I add/store only distinct values in multivalued field?

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm trying to have multivalued field which should store only unique values in it. 
    When I'm trying to add values using partial update(atomic update using "add").
    it should not add value if it already exists in that multivalued field.

```
For example:
<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>    

first adding values into field :
{"id":"36",
 "name":["RAJEEV CHAUHAN","Alex"]
}
Now values in the "name" field  are as follows"name":["RAJEEV CHAUHAN","Alex"].


second time when I add using partial update "add" as below,
{"id":"36",
 "name":{"add":["RAJEEV CHAUHAN","Alex","ERICK"]}
}
Now the values in the field should be "name":["RAJEEV CHAUHAN","Alex","ERICK"], it should not be 
 "name":["RAJEEV CHAUHAN","Alex","RAJEEV CHAUHAN","Alex","ERICK"]

How can I achieve these functionality?

Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible. You would be better to read the value in your client, and post an update using the "set" command instead of "add" - eg.

```
{ "id": "36",
  "name": { "set": [ "RAJEEV CHAUHAN","Alex","ERICK" ] }
}
```